# jQuery - My first plugin, how to prevent duplicate application to an element

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have the following:

```
$('.comment_content').live('focus click', function() {
    $(this).bTextAreaResizer();
});
```

I need it live on click because the comment_content boxes appear dynamically sometimes after page load. I just noticed that this is continuing to reapply the bTextAreaResizer() to the textarea each time which brings the browser to a stopping halt. In the plugin I have:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.bTextAreaResizer = function(options) {

    return this.each(function() {

        //bind events
        $(this).bind('scroll keyup', function() {
            resizeTextArea($(this));
        });
```

How can I say, only bind to this element if we haven't already? Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a better way, but to avoid duplicate event binding, you could *unbind* the events before. You can use [*event namespaces*](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events) for that. And btw, you don't need to loop over all the elements in this case:

```
return this.unbind('.btar')
           .bind('scroll.btar keyup.btar', function() {
                resizeTextArea($(this));
           });
```

Comment: Thanks but that binds,unbinds, over and over. given that my live is on focus on click... how in the plugin can I check to see if it is already binded and if not Then bind?

Comment: @TheExit: True. As I said, I guess there is a better way for your particular situation... And I think you cannot test it. The `undbind`, `bind` example is given at the event namespace page as an example for handling adding event handlers after an Ajax call. If there was another way, they would use it.